# Most general 4-fermion EFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, fermions, effective-field-theory

In order to understand EFTs, I'm trying to work with an example, the 4-fermion theory in the IR:
$$\mathcal{L}^\text{IR}=i\bar{\psi}\hat{\partial}\psi-m\bar{\psi}{\psi}+\text{all operators allowed by symmetry}$$
To parametrize the operators mentioned above, one can use *Wilson coefficients* $c_{n,k}$ where $n$ is the number of fields, and $k$ is the number of derivatives, and I want to write the operators up to order $n=4,k=2$.

What my notes say is
$$\mathcal{L}^\text{IR}=\mathcal{L}^\text{IR}_\text{kin}+c_{4,0}\bar{\psi}{\psi}\bar{\psi}{\psi}+c_{4,2}\partial_\mu\bar{\psi}\partial^\mu{\psi}\bar{\psi}{\psi}+d_{4,2}\partial_\mu\bar{\psi}\partial^\mu{\psi}\bar{\psi}{\psi}$$ where the $c_{2,k}$ aren't present because they already appear in the kinetic part. My question is: **how do I demonstrate that other operators are redundant?**

I know that I need to use integration by parts and the Equation of Motion (EoM) but **what equation of motion should I use?** The classical $(i\hat{\partial}-m)\psi=0$? Or should I also include the term $c_{4,0}$ and use $(i\hat{\partial}-m-2c_{4,0}\psi\bar\psi)\psi=0$?

Comment: @CosmasZachos with a gamma matrix?

Comment: But moving the derivative to the gamma matrix, using Freezing and int by parts, produces the Dirac operator.

Comment: @CosmasZachos what's "freezing"? Also, this doesn't exclude the $k=3$ term, right?

Comment: Sorry, Fierzing. The spellchecker went berserk. My impression is the 3-gradient case, also involving a gamma has the same fate...

Comment: @CosmasZachos I modified the question to make it more precise, I don't know if this makes it easier to answer

Comment: I do not have the standard references that do this for you, but I know they exist and there are *many*.  I think you just use the classical equation of motion.